# How can I do exact match begin with in JQuery Autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete, azure-cognitive-search

I have implemented autocomplete in my application and using azure search for suggestion. But currently it's giving suggestion if the matches found in between line. But I want to search it begin with of given term like if I type What is  then it should

- what is first name
- what is second name
- what is third name

but currently its returning like

- By the way what is
- what is first name
- what is second name

Please see below code which I am using

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
                    source: "/home/suggest?username=myname&",
                    minLength: 3                   
                });


$.ui.autocomplete.filter = function (source, term) {
            var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");
            return $.grep(source, function (value) {
                return matcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
            });
        };
```

Comment: Just for clarity, what are you trying to do with this logic? `return matcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);`

Comment: @Taplar thanks for quick reply. I am also confuse with this line... when I was googling I found this suggestion.

Comment: Can you please format your question so that the explanation of the expected and actual results is clear? Maybe use quotes, or line-breaks, or something? Otherwise it's difficult to understand your question. Also, please share the code that's calling your Search service. It looks like this JS code is calling your own API that in turn calls Azure Search.

Comment: @BruceJohnston could you please suggest me. i have formatted my question

Comment: @Ajay Please share the code that’s calling Azure Search (whatever code is behind /home/suggest). That way we’ll know which API you’re calling and what parameters you’re passing.

Comment: @Taplar That'll try the regex match against the first non-falsey among `value.label`, `value.value` or `value` type-coerced to a string. That's usually the (json) format for autocomplete data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `source` to a string, autocomplete doesn't use its internal `filter` function. To do post-request filtering, handle the request yourself:

```
source: function( request, response ) {
    var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );

    if ( this.xhr ) {
        this.xhr.abort();
    }

    this.xhr = $.ajax( {
        url: "/home/suggest",
        data: $.extend({username:"myname"}, request),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function( data ) {
            response(
                $.grep( data, function( value ) {
                    return matcher.test( value.label || value.value || value );
                } )
            );
        },
        error: function() {
            response( [] );
        }
    } );
}
```

Explanation:

`filter` isn't part of the widget's API. You **should not** overwrite the library's internal functions without very good reason.

Instead, manually handle post-filtering with the `source` option. The second parameter `response` provides a callback for any result you want to pass to the widget. Handle the AJAX call manually and then process the result before passing it back to `response`. [See here for an explanation of how `source` works.](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

Disclaimer:

**This is bad practice.** Filtering is done first on the server, by term, then on the client, by the `^` matcher. It sends unnecessary data over the network. It should be done at a single point. Either pre-load all data to the client, or just let the server handle the filtering.

Only use this if you both have no access to the server code and cannot pre-load.